# Must I always use RequestHandler to make Endpoint with Sveltekit?

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I am making some Todo website with this Video [svelte fullstack app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUzaUJ3gEug&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) 
and in this Video Teacher uses RequestHandler to make Endpoint..

But in this sveltekit documents they tell me use just normal function like that [body-parsing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-body-parsing)

So My Questions is "must i use RequestHandler or Could i use normal Function?"

Comment: A requesthandler is a specific type of function meant to be used in endpoints that corresponds to HTTP methods like GET and POST. If you want an endpoint, you need that function. Otherwise, it's not an endpoint to my knowledge. Also please clarify this question as its very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Koen seems to have got the idea. I believe you're confused about the TypeScript type that was used in the video.

```
export const get: RequestHandler = () => {
```

is the TypeScript equivalent of

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export const get = () => {
```

Which is the type safe Javascript equivalent.